# Session Expires on window server 2008 R2 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am working on an online recharge application in which I used session variable to store the request iD. If `Session["RequestId"]` matches with the request ID found in the response 
then only updating my database.

Everything works fine on my local environment but when deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) IIS 7.5 session variable are getting null after completing PG Transaction.

My web config settings are:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="30" ></forms>
</authentication>
```

I have checked IIS setting and recycling.All the settings has been set properly. I have googled but not found the reason why session variables are lost on server. Does anyone has any idea?

I am using VS 2010 with C# and Oracle.

Comment: what do you means by lost ?

Comment: @Hardik: I got null value in Session["RequestId"]after doing transaction.